# Android, Google Play - "The server could not process your apk. Try again." error

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, google-play

i repeatedly tried to upload my app, but every time upload crashed. Before uploading i cleaned and built project, then i exported it.

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.inzerujem"    
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />     
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />     
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />    
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >    
        <activity
            android:name=".InzerujemActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >    
            <intent-filter>    
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />    
            </intent-filter>    
        </activity>    
        <activity
            android:name="TopicActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >    
        </activity>    
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Thank you for answers.

Comment: Maybe add a target sdk version in the uses-sdk tag : <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

Comment: Added and still same problem.

Comment: is Android market down ?

Comment: They tend to have temp problems like these... Try again later today

Comment: I tried it yesterday with same problem. Is there any way to find if market is down?

Comment: Try the new console, it should solve this problem. However, the new console have problem just now, I can't upload my apk, it said:"Upload failed. We could not save your changes. Please try again". Don't know what's the problem.

Comment: this error can mean many things.. google just hasn't figured out how to give meaningful error messages. a lot of the time it is an error on their side and there is nothing that can be done except literally 'try again'. sometimes it's something in the manifest file, sometimes both. google really need to improve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package="com.android.inzerujem"
```

There's your problem. You are *NOT* allowed to use com.android for package names.